# How do i retrieve the value of "Password" input field, so that i can use this value to pass it to another function to check for validation ? REACTJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am a total Noob in reactjs. i want to perform a password check here. i want to first retrieve the value from the password input field, then pass that value to another function which would check that
entered password against various conditions such as presence of upper case, special characters numbers etc. all my code can accomplish right now is that i can console.log the individual changes everytime a character is typed in the password input field. I was trying to console log the final entered password on button click just to check if the entire password can be typed but i come up empty each time. as nothing is printed in console.

The end goal is not to get the value when i click the button, but just How to retrieve and store the value of the password field in a variable that i can pass to another check function.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
export default function Signup() {

function getData(val)
{
  var x=val.target.value
  console.log(x);
  return x
}
 
function print()
 {
   var y= getData();
   console.log(y);
 }
  return (
             
    <div className="main">
    <div className="sub-main">
      
     <div>
       <h1>Sign-up</h1>
       <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" className="name"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email" className="mail"/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" className="name"/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" className="pass" onChange={getData}/>
    
    </div>
    <div>
      <button className="button" onClick={getData}>Create Account</button>
    </div>
      <div className="link">
        
      <p>Have Account?<a href="/Signup"> Login Here</a></p>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 
  )
}
```

i was trying to use the getData function to return the final value of x. then i put y=getData() so that Y would store the value of my password. then i tried to console.log Y on button click. i think that Y never held the value of X to begin with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases like these it's usual to use the 'useState' hook.

Just declare :

```
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
```

Then you can use your variable pretty much everywhere it's needed. You set the value using 'setPassword'. You use the value using the variable, so 'password'.

Your code would look like this then:

```
function setData(val)
{
  setPassword(val.target.value);
}
 
function print()
{
  console.log(password);
}
```

...

```
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" className="pass" onChange={setData}/>
```

That should enable you to use the password, wherever you like.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it totally solved the issue!